# rolling dice do not understand this problem know it is going to be easy once I get it

Tags: probability

If a pair of dice are rolled, what is the probability that the sum is less than 7 or at least one of the die rolled is a 2?  I have tried to work this type of problem out and I just can't get an understanding.  HELP

Comment: The dice are green and red. Imagine recording the result as $(a,b)$ where $a$ is the number on the green, and $b$ the number on the red. Make a careful list of all "winning" patterns, count, and divide by $6^2$.  Then if you feel like it give a way of counting without explicit listing.

Comment: its helpful to know $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

Comment: Make a table with all the possible outcomes (six rows for the first die and six for the second).  Check off all the boxes where the sum is less than 7 or at least one die is a 2.  Count the boxes.  That will give you the answer.  Now think about how you could summarize this counting procedure in a formula.  That will tell you how to more quickly find such answers in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this problem using the classical definition of probability.

First understand your events here. Two die are rolled. What is your sample space then? It's $\Omega=$ {$(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6),\ldots (6,1),(6,2),(6,3),(6,4),(6,5),(6,6)$}. So the total number of cases is $36$.

Now, your first event is that the sum is less than $7$. So what can the sum be then? The minimum number you can get on each die is $1$, so the minimum sum has to be $1+1=2$. So the sum here can be $2,3,4,5,6$.

Sum is $2$ for the case $(1,1)$.

Sum is $3$ for the case $(1,2),(2,1)$.

Sum is $4$ for the case $(1,3),(3,1),(2,2)$

Sum is $5$ for the case $(1,4),(4,1),(2,3),(3,2)$

Sum is $6$ for the case $(1,5),(5,1),(2,4),(4,2)(,3,3)$

So the total number of favorable cases is $15$.

So your probability of getting a sum of less than $7$ is $\frac{15}{36}$

Now, the next event is getting at least one $2$ and here the cases are: $(1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2),(6,2),(2,1),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6)$

So the number of favorable cases is $11$

So your probability of getting at least one $2$ is $\frac{11}{36}$

Now, what is the probability that both of these occurs, i.e. You get at least one $2$ and the sum is less than $7$?

What are the cases then? $(2,1),(2,2),(1,2),(2,3),(3,2),(2,4),(4,2)$

So the number of favorable cases is $7$ and the probability is $\frac{7}{36}$

Now, there's a result that says $P(A\cup B)= P(A)+ P(B) -P(A\cap B)$, where $ P(A\cup B)$ is the probability of at least one of $A, B$ occurring and $ P(A\cap B)$ is the probability of both $A, B$ occurring.

Using that result here:

Required Probability= $\frac{15}{36} +\frac{11}{36}- \frac{7}{36}=\frac {15+11-7}{36}=\frac {19}{36}$

Answer (score 0):

We are given two events $A$ and $B$ and we have to calculate $P(A \cup B)$. By the principle of inclusion and exclusion, we have 
$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B).$$
The probability of getting a sum less than 7 is $P(A) = \frac {5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1}{36} = \frac {15}{36}$. The probability of getting at least one $2$ is $P(B) = \frac{6 + 6 - 1}{36} = \frac {11}{36}$ (we used inclusion and exclusion again while calculating $P(B)$). The probability of both events happening is $P(A\cap B) = \frac{7}{36}$. Thus $P(A \cup B) = \frac{15+11-7}{36} = \frac {19}{36}$.

Comment: Oops I should've read the problem more carefully. I edited the solution. Hopefully there isn't anymore errors.

Comment: Ok I found it. I counted the (2,2) case twice in $P(A\cap B)$.

Answer (score 0):

To be totally accurate, one would have to first ask if it is a standard pair of dice having 6 sides each and having them each marked 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 and if each outcome of them is equally likely (for example, not a "loaded" pair of dice or even one loaded die).

Also, for a problem like this with a small number of outcomes, it helps just to list all 36 outcomes (1,1), (1,2)...(6,6), and then pick the "winners" "by hand".

One of the "trickiest" things about counting problems (generally speaking) is making sure you count all the "winners" but making sure you don't count the same outcome multiple times.  Even for a "simple" problem like this it is possible to make that error as someone did but they quickly corrected it.